# In ProviderRepository.php line 208: Class 'Sentry\SentryLaravel\SentryLaravelServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel-5, sentry

I'm trying to install Sentry Error Tracking into my Laravel 5 Project. It throws an Error when i try publishing the Provider using the command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Sentry\SentryLaravel\SentryLaravelServiceProvider"
```

I added this into config/app.php

```
'providers' => array(
    // ...
    Sentry\SentryLaravel\SentryLaravelServiceProvider::class,
)

'aliases' => array(
    // ...
    'Sentry' => Sentry\SentryLaravel\SentryFacade::class,
)
```

Then i ran

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Sentry\SentryLaravel\SentryLaravelServiceProvider"
```

And it threw the Error

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
Class 'Sentry\SentryLaravel\SentryLaravelServiceProvider' not found
```

I've been searching for various solutions but none of them worked for me. This is very important for my project. Can i please please get some assistance. Thank You.

Comment: Is the package definitely present in your `vendor` directory? Have you rebuilt your autoloader?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend official sentry documentation.
https://sentry.io/for/laravel/

Not sure what is your exact development environment.(OS, PHP version, laravel version etc).

Here are something you can check.

1. check your installed sentry laravel package. If you did not install it, use next command to install.

> ```
> composer require sentry/sentry-laravel
> ```

2. check version of sentry/sentry-laravel from composer.json. 
   Please notice after version 1.x namespace has been changed to

> ```
> 'providers' => array(
>     Sentry\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class,
> )
>
> 'aliases' => array(
>     'Sentry' => Sentry\Laravel\Facade::class,
> )
> ```

**Namespace update**

version 0.x

```
Sentry\SentryLaravel\SentryLaravelServiceProvider::class

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-laravel/blob/0.10.1/src/Sentry/SentryLaravel/SentryLaravelServiceProvider.php
```

version 1.x

```
Sentry\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-laravel/blob/1.0.0/src/Sentry/Laravel/ServiceProvider.php
```